# Set maximum memory per process in Windows 8.1

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, memory-management

I am using a Toshiba laptop with 6.0 GB of memory running Windows 8.1. I've had it freeze up a couple of times due to a process trying to use more memory than the computer has available. I've been told it's possible to set a hard, per-process cap on memory usage, so the computer stops a process or forbids it from taking more memory rather than choke. I don't know how to do this, and Google searches have been unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me how to cap per-process memory use or point me to a resource that does?

Comment: It is not possible for a process to use more memory the amount of physical memory installed in the system.

Comment: @Ramhound: sort of. What happens is it starts paging memory to disk, which is hopelessly slow, causing my computer to freeze. The only solution I've found once that happens is a hard shutdown.

Comment: **The program is still not using MORE MEMORY then physically installed.**

Comment: @Ramhound: I understand that. However, our fancy modern operating systems are happy to _pretend_ that they can. I did use the word "trying" in my question.

Comment: NO;  They tell the process they can use all the physical memory, even if its not free, and figure out how to free it.  **The process does not and cannot use more memory then physically installed, there is a difference.**  Instead of trying to treat the symptom post the information required to determine the reason you have a process that attempts to allocate all your memory.

Comment: @Ramhound: OK, that makes sense. What I want to do is make my computer put that cap lower, say at half the physical memory. As to what process is causing it, it's happened through a couple of different programs, both of which were programming interpreters. The problem occurs when I try to perform an operation in my code that requires more memory than my computer has; this does not happen often, but it's really annoying when it does. I've done the same thing on an XP machine, which raised a `MemoryError` rather than freeze. I was told that it must of had the cap I'm talking about.

Comment: You can only limit the amount of memory a process within the code of the process otherwise process will use the amount of memory it requires to function.  It sounds like these programs having coding errors in them.

Comment: @Ramhound: I ran the code `range(10**9)` in the Python 2.7 GUI on both the XP machine and my 8.1 machine. This code generates an array containing all integers between 1 and 1 billion. Python uses 32-bit integers, so this should consume 4 GB plus the organizational overhead; this is less than my computer's total physical memory, but more than it had available. It's twice the amount of physical memory in the XP machine. On XP, Python raised a memory error immediately. On 8.1, it froze for about two hours before I killed it. Is this difference solely because of the difference in physical memory?

Comment: @Ramhound: Python isn't capping its own memory use: see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285185/python-memory-limit) and the following answers.

Comment: Your Windows 8.1 installation is a 64-bit installation.  You don't indicate if the Python process on the 8.1 installation is 32-bit or 64-bit which would make a huge difference.  Additionally unless you force Windows XP to allow a process to use more then 3GB then it wouldn't be possible for a 32-bit application to use 4GB of memory considering thats the hard limit of the entire system. Python documentation on `range(stop)` does not indicate the data type of `stop`

Comment: Everything else I have indicate is correct except for the 3GB limit. If I were to hazard to guess there is a check. Your code is not actually being ran on the 32-bit installation since the creation of that object is larger then 4GB and Python knows that.  This seems like more of a Stackoverflow question to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound: `stop` is an integer, in this case a 32-bit integer. The Python installation on 8.1 is 64-bit; on XP, it is 32-bit. I tried `range(25*10**7)` on the XP machine; this seemed to max out the physical memory, but did not raise a `MemoryError` or complete. However, the computer did not freeze, and I was able to kill the process through Task Manager.

Comment: If you had 8GB in the 64-bit installation of Windows 8.1 you could in theory double that number and you would get the exact same results. If you don't then its likely a problem with Python itself. Of course the limits of a 32-bit integer are exactly the same on a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. You sure the value you are providing to this function can even fit into a 32-bit integer?  Try this same function in Python 3 I suspect this might be a limitation of the function itself

Comment: @Ramhound: first, 10^9 < 2^31, so that shouldn't be a problem. In Python 3, they redefined `range`; you have to use `list(range(10**9))` to get the same effect. But back to my original question: is there no way to tell the operating system to not let any process use more than (say) 3.0 GB? I think you're saying the answer is no; please put that in the SE answer format, so it's clear to everyone.

Comment: I cannot write an answer at the quality that is required to publish an answer.  Furthermore I believe this to be better suited for Stackoverflow because the underline question is about python not a windows process.

Comment: A very similar question is discussed here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit